# Passing an array from an api call to a second api call

Tags: angular9, rxjs6

I am trying to make 2 api calls where one api gets the array of IDs that I needed to make another api call according to the IDs that were returned with some object where I can manipulate into displaying some form inputs according to the data I received from it.

But I am now stuck while attempting to make the second call. Any advice on how I could make the second call would be appreciated.

```
//api.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  baseurl = 'http://localhost:5000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getIds(id){
    return this.http.get(this.baseurl + '/types/' + id);
  }

  getCustomFieldsById(id){
    return this.http.get(this.baseurl + '/types/fields/' + id );
  }
}
```

```
//custom.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { map, mergeMap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom',
  templateUrl: './custom.component.html'
})

export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
  }

  getCustomFields(id){
    this.apiService.getIds(id)
    //this returns an obj in which arrayData constains an array of ids that is needs to be passed into the other api call
    .pipe(
      map((obj: any) => {
        //trying to map the array from the obj
        const data = obj.arrayData;
        return data;
      }),
      mergeMap(data =>
          //data here is an array of ids
          //suppose to receive the ids from the arrayData above 
          this.apiService.getCustomFieldsById(data)
      )
    ).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a series of `id` which in `ids`(arrayData), you can use `switchMap` instead of `map`:

```
this.apiService.getIds(id)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((obj: any) => {
        const data = obj.arrayData;
        return data;
      }),
      mergeMap(id =>
          this.apiService.getCustomFieldsById(id)
      ),
    ).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response); // response is a series of CustomField
    });
```

Or if you want to get a list of `customFields`, you can use `forkJoin`:

```
this.apiService.getIds(id)
    .pipe(
      map((obj: any) => {
        const data = obj.arrayData;
        return data;
      }),
      mergeMap(ids =>
          forkJoin(ids.map(id => this.apiService.getCustomFieldsById(id)))
      ),
    ).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response); // response is CustomFields[]
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried your way but now i am hit with TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Anywhere in between this that i did wrong? 

Edit: Ok never mind. I made it to work now. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @AndrewC sorry for just saw it, so glad to hear you got it !